# MVC6 ViewComponents Simple Example results in "Could not find an 'Invoke' method matching the parameters."

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to figure out the new ViewComponents feature in the simplest sense and am having trouble and the lack of documentation is not helping.

My first goal was to invoke my ViewComponent with a list of strings and have them be displayed.

The literally only guide I can find about ViewComponents is here and what I have based everything off of so far: http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/aspnet-vnext/vc#intro

I simply want to display a list of strings I pass into it in the invoke method, but can't seem to get the invoke method to work in the first place.

My folder/file structure is:

[image]

My very simple code is as follows:

**VcExampleViewComponent.cs**

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc;

namespace Mvc6Example3.ViewComponents
{
    public class VcExampleViewComponent : ViewComponent
    {
        public VcExampleViewComponent()
        { 
        }

        public IViewComponentResult Invoke(string[] strArr)
        {
            return View(strArr);
        }
    }
}
```

**Default.cshtml** (what the ViewComponent is supposed to be rendering)

```
@Model String[]

<h3>Strings passed in:</h3>
@foreach (String str in Model)
{
    <span>@str</span>
}
```

**Index.cshtml** (where the ViewComponent is invoked)

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>ViewComponent Example</h1>
</div>

@Component.Invoke("VcExample", new String[]{"hello", "hola", "bonjour" })
```

The error I get is:

> 500 Internal Server Error
>
> System.InvalidOperationException
>
> Could not find an 'Invoke' method matching the parameters.
>
> at Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ViewComponents.DefaultViewComponentInvoker.Invoke(ViewComponentContext context)
> at Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ViewComponents.DefaultViewComponentHelper.InvokeCore(TextWriter writer, ViewComponentDescriptor descriptor, Object[] arguments)
> at Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ViewComponents.DefaultViewComponentHelper.Invoke(String name, Object[] arguments)
> at Asp.ASPV__Views_Home_Index_cshtml.d__13.MoveNext() in /Views/Home/Index.cshtml:line 9

It could be something really trivial that I just overlooked but can't seem to find it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hmm, could you try and see if it works when you do not have parameters or when you just have a non-array parameter?

Comment: It may have something to do with the parameter being an array. Try reducing your code to take a single string parameter. If that works, try creating a class to wrap your string array and pass that instead.

Comment: @EvanMulawski Thank you, passing in a class that contained a string array (or presumably anything) worked - if you put that in an answer, I'll accept it and upvote it - thanks!